# What does the 'optimise' scala compiler flag do?

Tags: performance, scala, compiler-construction, compiler-optimization

I've tried using scalac `-optimise` with version 2.7.7. At that time I never got any performance improvements, but the compilation took longer.

Is the situation better in Scala 2.9.0 ? What optimisations are currently covered by the flag ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Strange, there was a [similar question on the scala-user group](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-user/browse_thread/thread/40b4e8db59dee55a/16820bdb47fa4949?lnk=gst&q=optimise#16820bdb47fa4949):

[Rex Kerr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/247533/rex-kerr) answered at the time (May):

> I have never found a case where production code was significantly sped up by
>   using `-optimise`, at least when using the Sun JVM.  I grant that in some
>   cases it could happen, but it seems to apply similar optimizations to what
>   the JVM does already.  Perhaps if there are limits on optimization depth,
>   using -optimise would remove a few layers and then allow the JVM to get a
>   few more.  But I mostly don't even bother testing it any more, given how
>   many cases (dozens) I've tried it where the runtime hasn't changed
>   measurably.
>
> I expect it would have an impact on VMs that are more conservative (e.g.
>   JRockit) or less sophisticated (e.g. Dalvik).

---

[Ismael Juma](http://blog.juma.me.uk) added:

> The scala distribution is actually compiled with -optimise, but indeed
>   it's not on unless the argument is passed to scalac.
>
> > Is it not mature enough, or could it lead to bugs, changed semantic, etc ?
>
> As far as I understand, the team decided to be conservative and enable
>   it only for the scala distribution as an initial step (in Scala
>   2.8.0). Maybe it's a good idea to consider extending that in the next
>   major release.

---

For the influence of '`-optimise`' (amongst other factors) in Scala2.9, see this [scala-language thread called "Scala2.9 slower?"](http://groups.google.com/group/scala-language/browse_thread/thread/94740a10205dddd2/b9bdbbb2b65cd21d?lnk=gst&q=optimise#b9bdbbb2b65cd21d).

> > I'm a bit concerned. After seeing that `-optimize` really does optimize "for comprehensions" on 2.9.0, I then benchmarked the code, and discovered it was about 2.5 times slower than 2.8.1.

The results leave a... mixed feeling.

Comment: It would be nice to have a definitive answer from the scala compiler writers regarding the status of this flag for scala 2.11